# как сделать чтобы скрипт поздравлений работал как надо?

Tags: javascript

```
var holidays = {
    '1': {
        '1': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': 'С новым годом !'},
        '7': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': 'С рождеством !'} },
    '2': {
        '23': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': 'С 23 февраля !'} },
    '3': {
        '8': {'start': 0, 'duration': 12, 'compliments': 'С 8 марта !'} },
    '4': {
        '12': {'start': 0, 'duration': 12, 'compliments': 'С днём космонавтики !'} },
    '5': {
        '1': {'start': 0, 'duration': 12, 'compliments': 'С 1 мая !'},
        '9': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': 'С 9 мая !'} },
    '6': {
        '1': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': 'С 1 июня, Всемирным днём родителей !'} },
    '7': {
        '3': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': '3 июля, день независимости Республики Беларусь !'} },
    '8': {
        '12': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': '12 августа международный день молодёжи !'} },
    '9': {
        '1': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': '1 сентября, день знаний !'} },
    '10': {
        '1': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': '1 октября, международный день пожилых людей !'} },
    '11': {
        '7': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': '7 ноября, день октябрьской революции !'} },
    '12': {
        '25': {'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': 'С католическим рождеством !'} }
},

    d = new Date(), m; // d = new Date( "9 May 2021 00:00:00:001" )

if((m = holidays[d.getMonth()+1]) && m[d.getDate()]) {
    m = m[d.getDate()];
    if(d.getHours()>=m.start) {
    var b = document.getElementById("holiday");
    if (!b) {
    b = document.createElement("div");
    b.id = "holiday";
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(b);
    }
    b.innerHTML = m.compliments;
    b.style.display = "block";
    }  
}
```

как исправить скрипт, чтобы например в строке

`{'start': 0, 'duration': 24, 'compliments': 'С новым годом !'}`

не указывать start и duration, и чтобы только в исключительных случаях была возможность изменить начало события с 00:00:00 и окончание события с 23:59:59 на другие значения с точностью до секунды (если речь идёт о событии в течении одних суток),
или чтобы только в отдельных случаях можно было указать начало события и продолжительность показа блока с точностью до секунд (если речь идёт о событии которое продолжается в течении нескольких суток)

попытаюсь объяснить подробнее, есть список дат, надо чтобы скрипт сверял текущий момент с этим списком, и в случае совпадения показывал блок с поздравлением, с точностью до месяца и числа, так возможно сделать? и только в отдельных случаях чтобы можно менять точность до часов минут секунд, а в других отдельных случаях чтобы можно было указать момент времени с точностью до часов минут секунд и установить таймер продолжительности показа блока в часах минутах секундах, так возможно?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (d.getHours() >= (m.start || 0)) {
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Igor, разве это поможет показать блок в промежуток времени с точностью до секунд?

Comment: Igor, разве это поможет показать блок в промежуток времени с точностью до секунд?